# How to get a row number or ID of where the MAX() value was found

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, rdbms

Good day community. 
I'm having a hard time trying to figure out a way to achieve the results I try to get. As im not very skilled with SQL queries, I start to lose my mind. What I'm trying to do is to find the highest and lowest grade on a particular test, but I also wish to get the ID or the row number (they are matching) of the rows where the MAX() and MIN() were found.

The table "Results" looks like this:

```
 ResultID|Test_UK|Test_US|TestUK_Scr|TestUS_Scr|TestTakenOn
   1         1       3      85          14     2018-11-22 00:00:00.000
   2         3       1      41          94     2018-11-23 00:00:00.000
   3         2       4      71          54     2018-11-24 00:00:00.000
   4         4       2      51          52     2018-12-25 00:00:00.000
   5         6       3      74          69     2018-12-01 00:00:00.000
   6         3       6      83          57     2018-12-02 00:00:00.000
   7         7       4      91          98     2018-12-03 00:00:00.000
   8         4       7      88          22     2018-12-04 00:00:00.000
   9         5       8      41          76     2018-12-08 00:00:00.000
   10        8       5      37          64     2018-12-09 00:00:00.000
```

The results I get when I run my query...

```
TestID|TopScore|LowScore|LastDateTestTaken
   1      94       85    2018-11-23 00:00:00.000
   2      71       52    2018-11-25 00:00:00.000
   3      83       14    2018-12-02 00:00:00.000
   4      98       51    2018-12-04 00:00:00.000
   5      64       41    2018-12-09 00:00:00.000
   6      74       57    2018-12-02 00:00:00.000
   7      91       22    2018-12-04 00:00:00.000
   8      76       37    2018-12-09 00:00:00.000
```

This is the queries I'm working on.

This query returns the results mentioned above

```
WITH
-- Combine the results of UK and US tests
    Combined_Results_Both_Tests AS(
                select ResultID as resultID, Test_UK as TestID, Test_UK_Scr as TestScore, TestTakenOn as TestDate from Results
                union all 
                select ResultID as resultID, Test_US as TestID, Test_US_Scr as TestScore, TestTakenOn as TestDate from Results),
--Gets TOP and WORST results of the tests, LastDateTaken (Needs to add ResultID!)
    Get_Best_and_Worst_Results_And_LastTestDate AS(
                SELECT TestID ,max(TestScore) AS TopScore ,min(TestScore) AS LowScore ,max(TestDate) AS LastDateTestTaken
                FROM Combined_Results_Both_Tests
                GROUP BY TestID)
--Final query execution
SELECT * FROM Get_Best_and_Worst_Results_And_LastTestDate
```

I've tried to achieve my desired results with something like this, which doesn't work and is also very inefficient. What I mean that it doesn't work, it is filled with dublicates, whenever the match is found on US and UK tests.

```
--Gets ReslutID of Min and Max values
    Get_ResultID_Of_Results AS(
                SELECT * FROM Get_Best_and_Worst_Results_And_LastTestDate A
                CROSS APPLY
                (SELECT ResultID FROM Results res
                WHERE   (A.TestID = res.Test_UK AND A.TopScore = res.Test_UK_Scr) OR
                        (A.TestID = res.Test_US AND A.TopScore = res.Test_UK_Scr) OR
                        (A.TestID = res.Test_UK AND A.LowScore = res.Test_UK_Scr) OR
                        (A.TestID = res.Test_US AND A.LowScore = res.Test_UK_Scr) OR
                        (A.TestID = res.Test_UK AND A.TopScore = res.Test_US_Scr) OR
                        (A.TestID = res.Test_US AND A.TopScore = res.Test_US_Scr) OR
                        (A.TestID = res.Test_UK AND A.LowScore = res.Test_US_Scr) OR
                        (A.TestID = res.Test_US AND A.LowScore = res.Test_US_Scr)) D)
SELECT * FROM Get_ResultID_Of_Results
```

This is the results I'm trying to achieve (extra columns that would state where Max value and Min value was found) that would state the ResultID from Results table. Also, the row numbers match the ResultIDs in the table.

```
TestID|TopScore|LowScore|LastDateTestTaken    |MaxValueLocID|MinValueLocID|
   1      94       85    2018-11-23 00:00:00.000       2             1
   2      71       52    2018-11-25 00:00:00.000       3             4
   3      83       14    2018-12-02 00:00:00.000       6             1
   4      98       51    2018-12-04 00:00:00.000       7             4
   5      64       41    2018-12-09 00:00:00.000       10            9
   6      74       57    2018-12-02 00:00:00.000       5             6
   7      91       22    2018-12-04 00:00:00.000       7             8
   8      76       37    2018-12-09 00:00:00.000       9             10
```

Asking for any help with the solution, theoretical or even practical. Thank you!

Comment: It doesn't look like a Max(), Min() thing, for example in first sample how come highest is 94 and lowest is 85 for Id = 1 (where does that ID come from anyway)?

Comment: @CetinBasoz if you have a look at the Results table, you can see that Test_UK and Test_US have ID's. They both represent tests taken in two separate countries (same test hence the ID), what I'm trying to do is to find a highest and lowest scores for the tests. So Results row 1 and 2 in UK test with ID 1 got 85 and in US (row 2 of results) it got 94, hence max 94 and lowest 85.

Comment: But for first row highest and Lowest is not 94, 85 but 94 and 14. So it is more than that. Not max, min but US vs UK?

Comment: @CetinBasoz, you can say it that way, it's more of finding the highest and lowest score for that particular test in both countries combined. Hence the union.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I follow correctly, you want to unpivot the data and aggregate:

```
select v.testid, max(v.score), min(v.score) max(v.TestTakenOn)
from results r cross apply
     (values (Test_UK, TestUK_Scr, TestTakenOn),
             (Test_US, TestUS_Scr, TestTakenOn)
     ) v(testid, score, TestTakenOn)
group by v.testid;
```

Then you can modify this using window functions:

```
select v.testid, max(v.score), min(v.score) max(v.TestTakenOn),
       max(case when seqnum_desc = 1 then resultid end) as resultid_max,
       max(case when seqnum_asc = 1 then resultid end) as resultid_min
from (select r.resultid, v.*,
             row_number() over (partition by v.testid order by v.score asc) as seqnum_asc,
             row_number() over (partition by v.testid order by v.score desc) as seqnum_desc
      from results r cross apply
           (values (Test_UK, TestUK_Scr, TestTakenOn),
                   (Test_US, TestUS_Scr, TestTakenOn)
           ) v(testid, score, TestTakenOn)
     ) v
group by v.testid;
```

Comment: Not so good with SQL, and also receiving a syntax error. For whichever reason, the v.testid cannot be bound. Any particular reason for that?

Comment: Apologies, I figured it out, but it still not exactly it, as It finds the min and max from the row, while I need it to be found based on the ID in Test_UK and Test_US and Scr columns, I'll add the results generated by your query into the original question. And you will see what I mean

Comment: @Mr.Softy . . . The results should be what you want now.  I fixed the typo.

Comment: Brilliant, for a bit of reference, if someone wants to use this as a reference in the future, there is one more typo before max(v.TestTakenOn) selection. There are some mismatches in column names, but that minor. Excellent answer!

Comment: @Mr.Softy . . . This method should be both faster and more concise than a method that uses `union all`, `group by`, and `join`.

Comment: I looked it up, I do agree with you now. Will be using this method, I will only split the subquery into two. Changing my selection for the answer. Thank you Gordon.

Answer (score 1):

```
with allScores (TestId, Score, TestTakenOn, valueLoc) as
(
  select [Test_UK], [TestUK_Scr],[TestTakenOn], ResultId from scores
  union all
  select [Test_US], [TestUS_Scr],[TestTakenOn], ResultId from scores
),
maxMin (TestId, MaxScore, MinScore, LastTestDate) as (
  select TestId, Max(score), Min(score), Max(TestTakenOn)  
  from allScores
  group by TestId
)
select mm.*, a1.valueLoc as MaxValueLoc, a2.ValueLoc as MinValueLoc
from maxMin mm
inner join allScores a1 
on mm.TestId = a1.TestId and mm.MaxScore = a1.score
inner join allScores a2 
on mm.TestId = a2.TestId and mm.MinScore = a2.score;
```

[DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=aa6081fe53f8816e9765550b7d4df7b6)

Comment: @Mr.Softy, pity you can't, just try to run. I forgot to add the MAxValueLoc and MinValueLoc. Edited to add them.